# intermittent responses with node.js/ socket.io after authorization handshake

Tags: node.js, cakephp, socket.io

Ok I have a WAMP installation with cakePHP under windows xp 64 bit. I am using a websocket PHP pluging with the latest node 8.17  and socket io version .9.13. None of my co workers seem to know what the problem is and i have been stuck for two weeks. I was able to narrow down the problem, but I have no clue on how to fix it.

After my cakephp plugin makes the request to a socket io server i can capture the authorization handshake request however according to the socket io protocol the response body should contain the handhshake id, the heartbeat interval, the timeout interval etc... Sometimes I would get the proper response however the majority of the times(like 90 %) of the time I would get a null body response but the headers return 200 ok response which throws an error in my application. Is there a way I can get consistant results. I am more that happy to post debug information so you can see what I am talking about. I read somewhere that it might be gzip compression problem but with the socket io update i believe that has been fixed.
Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Comment: figured it out. For those of using socket.io cakephp plugin their was a problem in line 80. I believed the author was issuing a post instead of a get,which  i dont know why the response would be intermittent but i commented the line out and created a new HttpSocket object and manually issued the correct get request.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with line 80 of mgcrea/cake_websocket plugin. For some reason although it was issuing the correct request it was receiving at intermittent response. When i overrode it it then solved the problem.